# Spectrum counts only at initial few channels on MCA from scintillator?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, experimental-technique

I have two scintillators of the same kind, but they differ slightly in geometry and build. I'm testing them on the same PMT using different sources of gammas, neutrons, and alphas, but for one detector I'm not getting counts beyond about 70 channels (total 1024 channels) and the other detector is going well over 400 or even 600 channels (similar spectra, one just squeezed in). What might be the issue, since I expect them both to be similar?

Comment: Are you sure you had same voltage to PMT each time?

Comment: And are you sure you had same settings on your MCA for both runs?  It sure sounds like one of these is causing your discrepancy.

Comment: Recent question of some relevance: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/349120/photomultiplier-pulses-only-at-first-few-channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three obvious places to look for differences:

- The two tubes might be receiving different amounts of light on the photocathode.

  This could be due to different photocathode areas, different photocathode geometry relative the optical path<sup>1</sup>, or differences in the optical coupling (which might depend on light guides if you have any in the system).
- Different tube gains.

  You haven't said if you've done any gain matching, and PMTs vary in the voltage-gain curves. Just because you provide the same voltage to two tubes doesn't mean you get the same gain. There are often very large difference between properly working tubes of different designs or between tubes of the same design using different bases. There are also (usually modest) difference between tubes of the same design using the same bases even when both tubes are working properly. Damaged tubed may work to some degree, but with much reduced gain.
- Differences in the amplification chain.

  A commentator mentioned the MCA settings, but if pre-amps are involved you need to worry about those as well.

Debugging a system like this calls for isolating each component in turn.

1. Start with the raw tube gains; if you have the equipment, put the PMTs in a test rig that sends very low intensity light<sup>2</sup> and read out the pulses on directly an oscilloscope so that you can measure the single-photoelectron gain of the tubes. If there are pre-amps in the bases you may or may not be able to skip them by choosing the right output point.
2. Then check the (rest of the) amplification chain. Use a pulse generator and an oscilloscope to measure this if you don't trust the dials or documentation.
3. Then check the optical coupling. Use a single source and fixed geometry between source and scintillator so that you know both tubes see about the same rate of pulses from the scintillator, and compare *rates* rather than gains of the tubes. You'll need to correct for the quantum efficiency of the tubes—read the datasheets. If one arrangement has a lower QE-corrected rate then it's optical path may be losing a lot of light resulting in lower pulses.

---

<sup>1</sup> PMT designers can trade off solid angular acceptance for photocathode area, quantum efficiency, or repeatability. While many PMTs are designed to accept light from something approaching *"anywhere in front of the tube"* there are special purpose models that accept light from a much more restricted set of directions in order to improve some other technical parameter. If you put one of the latter kind into a system with your light coming from the 'wrong' direction relative the tube you're going to get disappointing results. The only practical way to know this is to read the manufacturer's documentation for the model.

<sup>2</sup> If your source for this is stable enough you can also use the data you get here as a measure of the relative quantum efficiency of the tubes which means you don't have to trust the datasheets in step (3).

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the same PMT it sounds like the problem is either the voltage applied to the PMT or the MCA settings. A light leak from changing scintillators would just make spectrum noisy not smaller. Since the small spectrum looked good, except for being compact, it sounds like one of the 2 options I mentioned. Also, make sure you used the same power supply for the PMT. I think when you turned voltage off PMT to change scintillators you inadvertently set it to a different voltage when you turned it back on. Just a hunch.